# Google Blogger Api Error. How to fix this?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, blogger, google-blogger-api

When I'm trying to publish a post using blogger api i'm getting this error. But I don't exceeded daily limit. I use this api around 4000 times. Today im getting this error.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/(_MY_ID_Here)/posts?isDraft=false&alt=json returned "We're sorry, but one or more limits for the requested action have been exceeded.">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many blog posts did you create on that day? According to this [support ticket](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/64728872?hl=en), you can only create a maximum of 100 posts per day, which causes the same error message you are getting. This is unrelated to how many requests you did on that same day.

Comment: No , i did not cross 100 limits today. Today i didn't use this api.

Comment: I would wait until at least 24 hours pass by and then try again. Some users are experiencing the same thing from around 50 posts.

Comment: Fine to hear that it is working now! I read more people saying that the behaviour of the API is inconsistent regarding the quota limits.